# How to stop symfony2 to create session cookie or how can i encrypt session in config.yml?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to encrypt session data which is active after and before login in **symfony2**.

Is there any option which will make session cookie data encrypted

```
session:
  name: php_sess_id
  save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/cache/sessions
  cookie_secure: true
  cookie_httponly: true
  cookie_lifetime: 0
```

Is this possible to stop sending session cookie with symfony2 or encrypt the session cookie data.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `Symfony 2.1+` on the contrary to `2.0` only creates session when necessary. Therefore, if you're seeing `PHPSESSID` it means than some component is using it.

You could always set up `HTTPS`. That way everything will be encrypted...